# Node - GraphQL - Ad.user field type must be Output Type but got: undefined

Tags: node.js, output, undefined, graphql, circular-dependency

I seem to be having circular dependency problems with using UserType inside AdType.

This is my UserType file: [UserType](https://github.com/milostomsik1/getbike.online/blob/master/backend/App/User/user.graphql.model.js)

This is my AdType file: [AdType](https://github.com/milostomsik1/getbike.online/blob/master/backend/App/Ad/ad.graphql.model.js)

If I try to use the code below I get the error "Ad.user field type must be Output Type but got: undefined" even tho I imported the UserType properly.

```
import { UserType } from '../User/user.graphql.model'
import { UserSchema } from '../User/user.mongoose.model'

const user =  {
  type: UserType,
  resolve(parentValue, args) {
    return UserSchema.findById(parentValue.user);
  }
};

//------------------------------
// Ad Type
//------------------------------
export const AdType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Ad',
  fields: () => ({
    id,
    user,
    title,
    views,
    availability,
... more code
```

If I try to console log UserType inside AdType after importing it, it says undefined, but when I use it as:

```
//------------------------------
// Ad Type
//------------------------------
export const AdType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Ad',
  fields: () => ({
    id,
    user: {
      type: UserType,
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        return UserSchema.findById(parentValue.user);
      }
    },
    title,
... more code
```

it works as intended, it just doesn't allow me to pull out the code to separate constant.
All other Types I import and use in the same manner work as expected, importing Ads into Users works as well, but importing User into Ads seems to break. It's basically the same code in both, just different info.

Comment: I am already using fields: () => ( { } ) to lazily load fields to avoid problems with circular dependencies, so this problem is really banging against my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am already using fields: () => ( { } ) to lazily load fields to avoid problems with circular dependencies, so this problem is really banging against my head.

But you are not doing it correctly. Javascript does not have lazy evaluation. This means that the value of `user` is not determined when the function is called but at the point in time when the `const` variable definition is evaluated. At this point the variable `UserType` holds no value and thus is undefined. Your object definition needs to happen when the function is called. If it is still not clear I can offer to go into detail how your types are resolved.

Try defining the user type inline or make it a function:

```
const user = () => ({ type: UserType, /* ... */ })

export const AdType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Ad',
  fields: () => ({
    id,
    user: user(),
    title,
    views,
    availability,
```

I am not sure why you pull your fields into seperate constants, your code does not seem that big that it improves readability but of course I can be wrong.

Okay, let's see how modules are resolved. To make this easier I use CJS because you most likely transpile the code down anyways and ES modules are just slowly coming to node.

```
// user.graphql.model.js
const adModule = require('ad.graphql.model.js');

// Node tries to resolve ad.graphql.model.js
const userModule = require('user.graphql.model.js');
// Ups, this one has been resolved already and required this as dependency.
// We have no other choice than to assign an empty object here
// userModule is {}
const user =  {
  type: userModule.UserType, // undefined
  resolve(parentValue, args) {
    return UserSchema.findById(parentValue.user);
  }
};
// finish this module and return to user.graphql.model.js
// adModule now contains the resolved module
const adModule = require('ad.graphql.model.js');
// finish module and replace {} with actual module content in ad.graphql.model.js
// userModule contains UserType
const userModule = require('user.graphql.model.js');

const ads = {
  type: new GraphQLList(asModule.AdType), // GraphQLObjectType
}

// Now your Schema does build/inits itself after the config has been specified
// (and all modules have been resolved)
// imagine user being a function now taht is called on Schema init
const user = () => ({
  type: userModule.UserType, // GraphQLObjectType
  /* ... */
})
```

Comment: What I've meant is that I'm using () => ( { } ) for fields because my code already broke when I used fields: { user: .... } syntax because it caused circular dependency, so I've fixed it that way.

What I don't understand is why only UserType makes that problem and not CategoryType, SubcategoryType and others which are imported the same way UserType is.

I decided to structure my code that way because I am expecting the code to grow a lot so I don't want to be caught up in messy code later.

Comment: Yes but just using the function arguments does not solve the problem if you dont reference **inside** of the function call. Going through the variable resolving takes time but I can write this down in the answer if you need it.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to say in this last comment. 
Defining const user = () => ({ type... }) worked, and I understand it works because it executes the code when const AdType = ... is executed. What I don't understand is why only UserType is making this problem. Inside User model I'm referencing AdType the same way and it's not making any problems. I'm also using CategoryType and SubcategoryType which are structured the same way just with different data and it's not bugging.

Comment: Your category and subcategory are not the same, they use the function definition that creates the object at call time. Why only one of the types is undefined is because of they way modules are resolved. I wrote about this in an edit to my post.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it a bit clearer for me. I didn't know require module resolving worked that way. I appreciate your help a lot! Is there possibly more elegant way to solve this problem than using function return?

Comment: I would really advice to inline the fields or use the very popular schema definition language that is for example very easy to use with https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-yoga or with https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools. This will easily scale to a couple hundred types. We have ~40 object types and its still manageable within one folder and field inlines. Especially if your resolvers are basically just delegating to mongoose