# GraphQL Missing a Name

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

Just learning GraphQL using both node and c#. I am trying to port the C# example over to node since it will be a good learning exercise (since I don't know node or graphql that well)

I have 2 types. Account and Owner (i.e. account owner)

Everything works fine with the following (i.e. Fields for Owned Accounts (list) and First Account (single object)

```html
module.exports = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'OwnerType',
    fields: {
        Id: { type: GraphQLID},
        Name: {type: GraphQLString},
        Address: {type: GraphQLString},
        OwnedAccounts: {
            type: new GraphQLList(AccountType),
            name: "OwnedAccounts",
            resolve(obj, args, { mssqlConfig }){
                return mssql_account(mssqlConfig).getByOwnerId(obj.Id);
            }
        },
        FirstAccount: {
            type: AccountType,
            name: "FirstAccount",
            resolve(obj, args, {mssqlConfig}){
                 return mssql_account(mssqlConfig).getFirstByOwnerId(obj.Id);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The issue arises when I try to add a field for AccountOwner to the AccountType. I get the error "One of the provided types for building the Schema is missing a name."

I have tried putting a name on everything I could see which didn't help at all.

The offending AccountType definition is:

```html
module.exports = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'AccountType',
    fields: {
        Id: { type: GraphQLID },
        Description: { type: GraphQLString },
        OwnerId: { type: GraphQLID },
        Type: { type: AccountTypeEnum },
        AccountOwner: {
               type: OwnerType,
               resolve(obj, args, { mssqlConfig }){
                    return mssql_owner(mssqlConfig).get(obj.OwnerId);
               }
        }
    }
});
```

If you need further info or any other code please let me know.

EDIT: If I change the declaration of the two types (Account and Owner) and put them in the same .js file then it works (see below). I have also changed the fields to return an arrow function which I believe will delay some kind of binding till after everything is loaded.

So now my question is how should I separate the types into different files. (JS isn't my strong point)

EDIT... altered Types...

```
const {
GraphQLObjectType,
GraphQLID,
GraphQLString,
GraphQLList
} = require('graphql');

const AccountTypeEnum = require('./accountTypeEnum');
const mssql_owner = require('../../database/mssql/owner');
const mssql_account = require('../../database/mssql/account');

const ownerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'OwnerType',
fields: () => ({
    Id: { type: GraphQLID, name: "Id"},
    Name: {type: GraphQLString, Name: "Name"},
    Address: {type: GraphQLString},
    OwnedAccounts: {
        type: new GraphQLList(accountType),
        name: "OwnedAccounts",
        resolve(obj, args, { mssqlConfig }){
            return mssql_account(mssqlConfig).getByOwnerId(obj.Id);
        }
    },
    FirstAccount: {
        type: accountType,
        name: "FirstAccount",
        resolve(obj, args, {mssqlConfig}){
             return mssql_account(mssqlConfig).getFirstByOwnerId(obj.Id);
        }
    }
})
}); 

const accountType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'AccountType',
fields: () => ({
    Id: { type: GraphQLID, name: "Id" },
    Description: { type: GraphQLString, name: "Description" },
    OwnerId: { type: GraphQLID, name: "OwnerId" },
    Type: { type: AccountTypeEnum, name: "Type" },
    AccountOwnerFoo: {
           name: "Wombat",
           type: ownerType,
           resolve(parent, args, {mssqlConfig}){
                return mssql_owner(mssqlConfig).get(parent.OwnerId);
           }
    }
})
});

module.exports = {
ownerType,
accountType
}
```

Comment: I think the enum is fine. Its just when I add 'AccountOwner' to AccountType that I get the error. If I make the AccountOwner field a GraphQLString type return 'foo' the error goes away and i can query and get 'foo' Something is wrong with the OwnerType.

Comment: have uploaded the prject to https://github.com/srosam/graphql-example-01

Comment: have you tried putting a `name` inside `AccountOwner` ?

Comment: Hi. not sure where you mean. The only one missing a name that I can see is Address on OwnerType

Comment: Seems like you figured it out. To deeply understand your problem you have to understand the module resolution algorith in Node.js for circular dependencies and how the arrow function delays the evaluation of the object types. I will try to link similar questions as dublicates

Comment: @SRosam The code on github is working. Can you create a separate branch where I can see the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Node.js allows circular dependencies. Not all module systems allow this but it works in Node. The problem is, that one of the modules needs to be undefined in whatever module gets parsed first. In this case, Node.js assigns an *empty object* as the export of this module.

So basically you are assigning an empty object as a type sometimes - thus complaining that the type is missing the name property. The good thing though is that the reference to this object will not change if you assign properties to it. What you have to do I have answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50669249/related-graphql-objects-giving-undefined/50670717#50670717) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286657/node-graphql-ad-user-field-type-must-be-output-type-but-got-undefined/48289780#48289780).

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to answer a question that is off-topic, you could either use a comment or two, or you can mark your answer as "community wiki" and then vote to close once the bounty is expired (I think answering as non-wiki and then also closing is discouraged, or at least used to be).

Comment: I agree there is a grey area, but duplicates are definitely closable. I don't know the exact reason why bountied questions can't be closed - maybe they just need to work out what the mechanics of a refund would be? Not sure, maybe one for Meta!

Answer (score 1):

why this error occurred? Because you are giving the type which is not defined at the compile time. So, when the compiler tries to compile the file, it searches the type you have specified here it is `AccountType`. which is not compiled. That's why the `OwnerType` didn't get the `AccountType` and you are getting an error.

Simple Solution:

You need to import the `AccountType` inside the `OwnerType` file.

`const AccountType = require('./AccountType.js');`

before the `OwenerType` code. This might be helpful.